# How do I rotate the OSM map before printing?

Tags: coordinate-system, openstreetmap, mapnik, rendering

What is the simplest way to rotate and render Openstreetmap data, and still get a nice render? For example [Toronto](http://www.openstreetmap.org/?lat=43.704&lon=-79.395&zoom=11&layers=M), would fit best rotated slightly on a page in landscape mode, so the northern boundary of the city are parallel to the top edge of the printed page.

Example: Toronto rotated here with Gimp, works fine but the labels are not really supposed to be rotated.

[image: Image of a Map slightly rotated (with bad label placement) see:]

The most common thing for Openstreetmap is to import the data into  PostgreSQL+postgis and render with Mapnik. But really any solution is fine, e.g. doing it in ESRI tools.

PS. This is a repost of a [question asked on help.openstreetmap.org](http://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/1736/how-do-i-rotate-the-osm-map-before-printing), I'll repost the answers there if I'm allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the same method as you have above but use the undocumented 'TextSymbolizer' Rotation (orientation)

http://trac.mapnik.org/changeset/1783

Here is another technique

[image]

(Map Rotated see North Arrow - Text remains horizontal)

http://ancalime.de/rotated.html

Comment: Hum, so no easy way to do this? Both of them are solutions but not really usable, we are talking hours of work to get a map rendered horizontally. Do you have examples of TextSymbolizer, and rotating Markers?

Comment: http://trac.mapnik.org/browser/trunk/tests/data/good_maps/text_rotation.xml

Comment: it doesn seem like we can rotate pointsymbolizers

Answer (score 2):

Using ArcGIS it is very easy to rotate the data frame.  Right-Click on the data frame, choose "Properties", and on the "General" tab, change the rotation value towards the bottom of the form.  To do it more interactively, open the "Data Frame Tools" toolbar where you can type a value or use the "Rotate Data Frame" button to interactively drag the rotation of the data frame.  You may need to play with the layers "Placement Properties" for labels to have them render horizontally, parallel (to lines), etc to fit your style.